# Getting error when trying to compile 64-bit shared library with NDK-build

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm, arm64

I'm trying to build an old `ndk` project to get the 64-bit shared libraries (arm64-v8a) but it only compiles `armeabi` (No APP_ABI mentioned at all).

When I try to build `arm64-v8a` libs (just had put APP_ABI = arm64-v8a in Application.mk) it gives the following error.
`Error: operand 1 should be an integer register --`str r2,[sp,#(1024+(14*4))]'`
Like the above line, it throws many similar lines of error in cmd. I'm building this from cmd, not Android studio or Eclipse.

I just want to build a 64-bit .so file without issue. Thanks for your help in Advance.

Comment: It seems like the library source contains some assembly code. Assembly is not portable, so you'll need to find or write corresponding arm64 assembly. Or if the library only uses the assembly as an optional optimization and also contains equivalent C code, then you could try switching to the C version (it would be up to you to figure out if and how that is possible for this library).

Comment: Yeah like you said only one file is in Assembly (.S extn). I'm new to this. Is there any way to make it work for arm64?

Comment: @NithisKumar It will need a re-write, or replacing with C/C++

Comment: @NithisKumar Given that ARM64 assembly is not backwards compatible to ARM32 assembly, you have to manually port the code over.  It's not a hard task but it requires knowledge of both ARM32 and ARM64 assembly.